# How to code in bash to send the jobs to the cluster

Tags: bash

```sh
for subj in ${SUBJECT_LIST[@]};
do  
    echo "module load freesurfer/7.1.1; recon-all -all -subjid $subj -sd $working_dir" | qsub -q long.q; done
```

It seems like the `$subj` in the quotation mark doesn't change. Is there a better way than using `echo` to load software and send the job?

Comment: Your code is lacking the assignment to `SUBJECT_LIST`.

Comment: Thank you Armali, you're right, but it's because I've removed the parts that are not related to the point of my question.

Comment: On the contrary - what is assigned to `SUBJECT_LIST` is crucial for the answer to your question.

Answer (score 0):

```
for subj in "${SUBJECT_LIST[@]}"; do  
  printf 'module load freesurfer/7.1.1; recon-all -all -subjid %q -sd %q\n' "$subj" "$working_dir" | qsub -q long.q
done
```

`printf %q` quotes its arguments properly for `bash`, I don't know what `qsub` expects, but maybe it is compatible.